# Getting Facebook App ID's via API Key/Secret

Tags: facebook, api, app-id, secret-key

I have a whole bunch of API Keys/Secrets from all of my old Facebook Apps stored in my database. However, Facebook does not support the API Keys only the App IDs, which I don't have. I have tried getting it via:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+app_id,api_key,+canvas_name,+display_name+from+application+where+api_key=322f44d0eec1544f6f3eea32a1af6142

but no dice, I can only select with App IDs like:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+app_id,api_key,+canvas_name,+display_name+from+application+where+api_key=19670737304

I'm not able to log users in or get their user IDs without their App IDs. Does anybody have any idea about how I could get them or am I not going to be able to get them?

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and select the App you're looking for and it shows the App ID and Secret

Comment: It was from an app builder and there are thousands of api keys.

Comment: And, they are not in my Facebook developer account.

Comment: Then you're out of luck, sorry.